# Retaining original functioon signature when overriding class function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, overriding

I have the following example code:

```
// I don't have control over class A
class A {
    func(a: string, b: int) {
        ...
    }
}

...

class B extends A {
    func(a, b) {
        return super.func(a, transform(b))
    }
}

...
function transform(x) {
    return ...;
}
```

I want `B.func(a, b)` to retain the original function type. Right now, `a` and `b` are implicitly `any`. How can I have `a` and `b` correctly typed (`string` and `int`), without explicitly re-assigning the types?

In principle, I want to achieve something like (pseudocode):

```
class B extends A {
    func(a, b) as typeof super.func {
        return super.func(a, transform(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: Abstraction won't work?

Comment: No, I don't have control over `class A`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by assigning a type to the function itself based on the `A` function type.  We use an indexed access to get the type of `A.func` as `A['func']`.

It's easy to write with an arrow function because you can insert the function type after the function name and before the `=`.

```
class B extends A {
    func: A['func'] = (a, b) => {
        return super.func(a, transform(b))
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Wkvk2m)